# Python ForkingTCPServer error

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

Help to build python ForkingTCPServer. This server returns an error when client connects to the server. When I use ThreadingTCPServer instead of ForkingTCPServer it works fine. socketFileIO module contains functions for pickle to/from socket: 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577667-pickle-tofrom-socket/

server.py:

```
import SocketServer, time 
from socketFileIO import write, read

class MyClientHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print self.client_address
        data=read(self.request)
        print 'Client:', data
        time.sleep(10) # for testing
        write(self.request,data)
        self.request.close()

HOST, PORT = '', 50007
server = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyClientHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

client.py:

```
import socket
from socketFileIO import write, read
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 50007
data=["A","B","C","End"]
for x in data:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    write(s,x)
    y=read(s)
    print 'Server:', y
    s.close()
```

Error:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 1469)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py", line 525, in process_request
    pid = os.fork()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fork'
----------------------------------------
```

I have a several other questions:

1. How to shutdown the server by sending data "End" from client ?
2. How to restrict the number of connections (for example no more then 5) ?

Comment: `os.fork` isn't available on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! In other words SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer not work on Windows?

Comment: Nope. You can probably write something similar with Twisted or `multithreading` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the answers to my other two questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fork question was already answered in comments.

For "how to shut down the server": in a similar application (but much older Python version and using xmlrpc), I used a loop invoking one request at a time until a "stop" variable was set.  This appears to be supported directly in Python 2.7 now: in your threaded server, call `shutdown()` on the server instance, from one of the request-handler threads.  (Not sure if this is available in 2.6, I de-installed my old 2.6 version a couple of months ago.)  I.e.:

```
class MyClientHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        ...
        # if we're supposed to shut down the server, do that
        if somecond:
            self.server.shutdown()
```

For limiting the number of connections: there's nothing built-in that I can see, but if you redefined the `process_request` handler you could count the number of active threads and wait for one to finish if there are "too many" outstanding (or work it however else you like).  See the `ThreadingMixIn` class in `SocketServer.py` and compare it to the `max_children` code in `ForkingMixIn`.